# Read from file, Sort list by revenue, Write to file

Tags: python

I'm given a text file of 500 films formatted as such:
"name"  \t  "gross revenue"

I've to write a function that sorts the films by gross revenue, then write the sorted content to the destination file.

I'm stuck on multiple counts and the error message that appeared is this:
`split[1]= int(split[1]) IndexError: list index out of range Command exited with non-zero status 1`

```
import re

def sort_films(source, destination):    
    source= open(source)
    destination = open(destination, "w")
    
    full_list=[]
    for line in source:
        split= re.split("\t|\n", line)
        split.pop()
        split[1]= int(split[1])
        
        full_list.append(split)
        full_list.sort(key= lambda i:i[1], reverse=True)
        
    print(full_list, file=destination)
        
    source.close()
    destination.close()
    
sort_films("top500.txt", "top500result.txt")
print("Done!")
```

Comment: In your own words, what do you expect `split.pop()` to do? How many elements do you expect the list to have after that? Now,  *test* your assumptions. Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and trace through the logic of your code. It's also helpful to try to pinpoint problems. You *don't know* if there is a problem with the sorting, because your code *doesn't get to that point*. So, you should ask about the code before that, and [try to write code that only solves the previous problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: (The `sort` call looks fine to me, but it's important to develop these skills - both so that you can diagnose and fix problems yourself, and so that you can ask top-quality Stack Overflow questions. It's also a good idea generally to write code following these principles. I'm sure you have heard "a function should do only one thing". That's what it means. Start by trying to make a function that accepts a *line from* the `source` file, and gives the appropriate parsed data.)

Answer (score 2):

You are removing the first element of a 2-element list, and then trying to access the second element of a now 1 element list. Either remove `split.pop()` or replace the index in `split[1] = int(split[1])` with a `0`.

Answer (score 0):

In bash you can achieve this easily with:

```
cat top500.txt | sort -n -k 2 > top500result.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only have two columns in file, you will get a 2-elements list when reading a row. Since "split" is a 2-elements list in each iteration, the pop() will delete the last element causing the list last only 1 element. Indexing "split" list with 1 will be invalid because "split" is now a 1 element list and python start indexing list from 0.

Answer (score 0):

I understand this is not the most elegant solution but hey.. this works. The problem was with your regular expression which did not give you the desired formatting.

you can give the below solution a try:

```
import re


def sort_films(source, destination):
    source = open(source)
    destination = open(destination, "w")

full_list = []
for line in source:
    line = re.sub("^\"|\"$|\n", "", line)
    split = re.split("\"    \"", line)
    split = list(filter(("").__ne__, split))
    split[1] = int(split[1])

    full_list.append(split)
    full_list.sort(key=lambda i: i[1], reverse=True)

print(full_list, file=destination)

source.close()
destination.close()

sort_films("source_file.txt", "out_file.txt")
print("Done!")
```